# How to track user statistics in cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am using cognito for an authentication platform and need a way to track how many users sign up per day, how many logins per day, failed logins, etc. I saw that there is something called pinpoint but it seems to be more of a messaging platform and geared towards Android and IOS.

Answer (score 7):

Yup, Pinpoint is what you're looking for. Here's an image of some basic statistics. On top of that, you can add custom events and metrics to gather practically any data about your app usage that you'd like. This includes everything you desire (as per your question).

[image]

From your "but" statement, it seems that you want something more than just a messaging platform and maybe something that isn't just for mobile [more info would help me answer with a more "pinpointed" response]. One of the major purposes of Pinpoint is to gather data **for the purpose of** running targeted campaigns. From Pinpoint, you can analyze your data and then make a targeted SMS / Push Notification campaign based on that data.

Nevertheless, Pinpoint is much much more than just a mobile platform. It is available in everything from C++ to Swift to PHP. Check out available languages here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/latest/developerguide/integrate-supported-sdks.html

Check out the following as well for more info:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/latest/userguide/welcome.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-mobile/latest/developerguide/add-aws-mobile-analytics.html

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can enable Cognito's Pinpoint integration. You will find some basic statistics that Cognito pushes to Pinpoint.

However, note that we don't support Javascript clients.

Here's a link to the docs
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-pinpoint-integration.html

Comment: When you say "we don't support Javascript clients" do you mean that pinpoint only works with ios and Android? Sorry if this is obvious, I just want to be sure.

Comment: Also I found pinpoints api's http://docs.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/latest/apireference/welcome.html and it looks like I may be able to use these to send analytic data such as user logins and such threw here using a Javascript client?

Answer (score 0):

Cognito does not track this type of information for you. You can customize the Cognito authentication flow to track this yourself.

[Customizing Amazon Cognito User Pool Authentication Flow](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/customizing-your-user-pool-authentication-flow/)

There are some stats that Amazon Pinpoint does collect for you. Take a look at Customer Analytics -> Retention Metrics.

[Retention Metrics](https://aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/customer-engagement/customer-analytics/)

Comment: Thanks for the response John. Just to be clear, this isn't something that pinpoint can capture is it?

Comment: I updated my answer with information about Retention Metrics.